# Trying to catch any error code when reading a json file with rapidjson

Tags: c++, linux, rapidjson

I am testing a very simple C ++ program in Linux that is capable of reading a json file.

This version of the program works:

```
#include "rapidjson/filereadstream.h"
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace rapidjson;

int main()
{
  char readBuffer[65536];

  FILE* fp = fopen("test.json", "r");
  FileReadStream is(fp, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer));

  Document doc;
  doc.ParseStream(is);
  fclose(fp);

  StringBuffer buffer;
  Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
  doc.Accept(writer);

  printf("test.json = %s\n\n", buffer.GetString());
  printf("TAG1 = %d\n", doc["TAG1"].GetInt());
  printf("TAG2 = '%s'\n", doc["TAG2"].GetString());
  printf("TAG3 = %d\n\n", doc["TAG3"].GetInt());

  return 0;
}
```

And it shows on the screen:

```
test.json = {"TAG1":10,"TAG2":"Text in tag 2","TAG3":2}

TAG1 = 10
TAG2 = 'Text in tag 2'
TAG3 = 2
```

Now I need to capture the possible errors that occur when parsing the content
of the json file. Looking in some internet forums, I have written this new version
from the previous program:

```
#include "rapidjson/filereadstream.h"
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
#include "rapidjson/error/error.h"
#include "rapidjson/error/en.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
using namespace rapidjson;

int main()
{
  char readBuffer[65536];

  FILE* fp = fopen("test.json", "r");
  FileReadStream is(fp, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer));

  Document doc;
  ParseResult result = doc.ParseStream(is);
  if (!result)
  {
    printf("JSON parse error: %s (%u)\n", GetParseError_En(result.Code()), result.Offset());
    exit (1);
  }
  fclose(fp);

  StringBuffer buffer;
  Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
  doc.Accept(writer);

  printf("test.json = %s\n\n", buffer.GetString());
  printf("TAG1 = %d\n", doc["TAG1"].GetInt());
  printf("TAG2 = '%s'\n", doc["TAG2"].GetString());
  printf("TAG3 = %d\n\n", doc["TAG3"].GetInt());

  return 0;
}
```

But when I compile it, I get these errors:

```
example.c: In function ‘int main()’:
example.c:20:39: error: conversion from ‘rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<> >’ to non-scalar type ‘rapidjson::ParseResult’ requested
   ParseResult result = doc.ParseStream(is);
                                       ^
example.c:23:91: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘std::size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("JSON parse error: %s (%u)\n", GetParseError_En(result.Code()), result.Offset());
```

I appreciate any comments or help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to complain that you use `(%u)` where you should use `(%zu)` in format string. See reference of [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Comment: I have made the change that you indicate and I see that the second error disappears.

Comment: example.c:20:39: error: conversion from ‘rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<> >’ to non-scalar type ‘rapidjson::ParseResult’ requested
   ParseResult result = doc.ParseStream(is);

Comment: About that it seemingly complains that ParseStream returns GenericDocument that can not be converted into ParseResult. It does it seemingly in plain English.